# Should I renew my ESTA if my point of contact has changed?

Tags: usa, esta

Two months ago I entered the United States for business purposes. The point of contact I specified was "Company X".

Now I need to visit the States again, for business purposes, but I'm visiting "Company Y". Should I submit a new ESTA application or should I keep the old one?

I know that submitting a new one doesn't hurt, and in fact that's what I have always done in the past. However I'm becoming sick of paying the fee every 3 months or so :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The circumstances that require a new ESTA are listed [here](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1072/~/about-the-electronic-system-for-travel-authorization-(esta)) and include only:

- passport change
- name change
- gender change
- citizenship change
- something happens (e.g. criminal conviction, overstay) that might cause the loss of the VWP privilege and require you to get a visa instead.

Otherwise the ESTA you applied for is good for 2 years regardless of how other information you included in the application changes.